# Laravel: I install intervention, but always get Class Intervention not found when coding

Tags: php, laravel

I have followed step by step the installation according to the web docs for intervention:

1) First I installed the latest version

```
$ php composer.phar require intervention/image
```

I have even repeated that step several times and I get the usual:

loading composer repositories,
updating dependencies,
nothing to install or update

2) Then I went to composer json and added this to providers

```
'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider'
```

and this to facades

```
'Image' => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image'
```

then I repeated composer update

I also did composer dump auto-load

and nothing. Whenever I try to used it on my docs it will tell me Class Intervention not found if I specifically use it like

```
Intervention::make('images/' . $filename . '.' . $extension);
```

If I do it otherwise like

```
$here = $image->move(public_path().'/img/gallery', $name); //to get the source of the uploaded file

Image::make($herei->resize('200','200')->save($name));
```

then it will tell me that it doesn't know what "resize" is, so, not a clue of Intervention.

I am flummoxed, been trying for 8 hours non-stop. Yes, I know there is a similar question here but the solution they provide is nothing new to what I have already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `Intervention` class. All calls are made to `Image`.

```
$image = Image::make('images/' . $filename . '.' . $extension);
```

Your second example doesn't work because you have to make an intervention image object before using `resize()`

```
Image::make($here)->resize('200', '200')->save($name);
```

Please read the [official documentation](http://image.intervention.io/) for more information

Comment: Thank you. I saw an example somewhere and instead of writing Image as you do, they wrote Intervention, and that baffled me. Your explanation says it all.

Comment: I got this error, which I remember I had it also before

Call to undefined function Intervention\Image\finfo_buffer()

I just copied and pasted the example from intervention, applying my path to my pic.

Comment: I got the solution to this latest error about fileinfo, had to uncomment the call in the php.ini file AND restart the server. Now, it works. Vielen Dank, bedankt. Merci.  Yes, we both found the same thread, that is where I found the solution, but all thanks to you.